# Order by String Date in MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, date, sorting

I have data into my table(Students) in MYSQL DB. I want to sort the data based on Date that is VARCHAR(50) column into the MYSQL Database.
So, I want a query like `Select *from Students where Date_Created => Now() Order by Date_Created`

Date_Created

````
2021-12-17
2021-12-16
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-15
2021-12-14
2021-12-14```
````

Comment: Why is a date stored as a string and not a `date` - that carries a lot of bagage, not least of which is the need to cast the string every time you need to perform date operations and queries will not be able to optimally seek to find rows (unsuargable).

Comment: what's wrong with the query you suggest?

Comment: So, what exactly you problem?

Comment: May be because once you use `DateCreated` and once `Date_Created` ?

Comment: you did not mention what is wrong in your question. If @SlavaRozhnev s comment and answer are correct, you should not correct your question as this will destroy the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below working query:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Date_Created >= Now() ORDER BY Date_Created;
```

[Test MySQL queries here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/804038a1b8521980d80e11ff5b2ce4da/)

Any way I recommend to use `date` type for store. dates in DB